# Docker Compose build fails to pull context from git repository over ssh

Tags: git, docker-compose, ssh

My docker service is a pretty simple one, it is defined in a docker-compose.yml file that looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  srv:
    build:
      context: git@mygitlabinstance:myusername/repo.git#master
      ssh: ["default"]
```

In older versions of Docker Compose, it was able to pull the context from the repo.git private repo without issues, using the same ssh private key as the host on which I'm running Docker.
I've upgraded to Compose V2 because it was long overdue.
I've added the default ssh agent element after noticing some problems, but this did not solve the issue.

The error I'm seeing is the following:

```
git@mygitlabinstance: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

A git clone using the same git url `git@mygitlabinstance:myusername/repo.git` works without issues.

I've tried running the following before attempting to run `docker compose build`:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
```

The commands ran without issues and `ssh-add -l` correctly lists the key used to connect to the private repo.

Am I missing something? I suspect the build context uses the wrong ssh key, but I'm unsure on how to test this. Is the build process running in a container?